# android how to subtract string from given string

Tags: android

I'm getting string in button. text I want to display only specific character only but when click show full value in toast how I will do that?

```
Button e01;
String[] days = new String[7];
e01.setText(days[1]);  // 2013/09/11
//i want to display only 11

@Override
public void onClick (View v){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.e01:
            value = e01.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(this, value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //value=// 2013/09/11
            break;
    }
}

calendarGlobal = Calendar.getInstance();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
calendarGlobal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, +currentweekno);
calendarGlobal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
String[] days = new String[7];
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  // days.add(df.format(calendarGlobal.getTime()));
  Log.d("TAG",df.format(calendarGlobal.getTime()));
  days[i] = df.format(calendarGlobal.getTime());
  e01.setText(days[1]);
  // ..
```

Comment: Hii,,, What is the string value? and what you wanna show?? Explain properly.. and Wht have you tried?

Comment: sorry but not able to understand your question what you really want ?
Do you want to set only the date value i.e 11 from 11/09/2013 to editText and then display the complete date on button click is it like that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show `11` from `2013/09/11` you can do it as -

```
String[] stringArray = days[1].split("/");
String elevenString = stringArray[stringArray.length-1];
```

Edit -

```
e01.setText(elevenString);
eo1.setTag(days[1]);
```

Now in onclick do this -

```
@Override
public void onClick (View v){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.e01:
            value = (String) e01.getTag();
            Toast.makeText(this, value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //value=// 2013/09/11
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: but i want to shoew full string in toast when click on button

Comment: ur code not work code is stop unexpectedly i think some problem on string array at thie line String[] stringArray = days[1].split("/");

Comment: days are also string of array    
 String[] days = new String[7];

Comment: What is value of days[1]?

Answer (score 0):

you can substract from the length.

```
String numbers = days[1].substring(days[1].length() - 8);
```

the date is 10 characters, minus 2 it gives last 11

Comment: and how i wil show full string in Toast when click on button?

Comment: String numbers = days[1].substring(days[1].length() - 8);

Answer (score 0):

Since you are showing a date then year is 4 characters + 2 for month + 2 /,then total of 6 characters you can use subString like below

```
Toast.makeText(this, value.substring(5), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

This should work perfectly.

NB:- Never use this way if the string is variable,not like this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] SeperatedDateValue= days[1].split("/");//days[1] = "2013/09/11"

/*SeperatedDateValue[0]//Year
SeperatedDateValue[1]//Month
SeperatedDateValue[0]//Day*/


e01.setText(SeperatedDateValue[0]);
```

And on Button Click

Display your date string as it is on the Toast by using your days[] variable values

Comment: i did like this  String[] stringArray = days[1].split("/");
          String elevenString = stringArray[stringArray.length-1];
          
   e01.setText(elevenString);
    e01.setTag(days[1]);
on e01.settext(elevenstring) show error code stop unexpectedly if i replay e01.text (days[1]); is work fine both show same string