# how to get specific value form arraysting

Tags: android

below is my code i want to show only specific value on text and when click show full value
this refrence not help me  [android how to subtract string from given string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800120/android-how-to-subtract-string-from-given-string)

```
               Button e01;
              String value;

            String[] days = new String[7];

             for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {


         Log.d("TAG",df.format(calendarGlobal.getTime()));
         days[i] = df.format(calendarGlobal.getTime());  

              //i want to display only 11
              days[1]=    // 2013/09/11
         String[] stringArray = days[1].split("/");
         String elevenString = stringArray[stringArray.length-1];

    e01.setText(elevenString);
    e01.setTag(days[1]);


    //e01.setText(elevenString); show error if i replace  /e01.setText(elevenString);
   ///   with  e01.setTag(days[1]);  is show same value on text and on click on toast i 
  //  want  to show only"11" on e01.setText("11");
  //  when click on e01 show full value on Toast   // 2013/09/11

                  @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {

      case R.id.e01:


      value = e01.getTag().toString();
             Toast.makeText(this, value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)    .show();








              public void calculateWeek(int currentweekno) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 //   days.clear();
    // Set the calendar to monday of the current week
    // calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
     calendarGlobal = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    calendarGlobal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, +currentweekno);
    calendarGlobal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
    String[] days = new String[7];
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
     //   days.add(df.format(calendarGlobal.getTime()));
         Log.d("TAG",df.format(calendarGlobal.getTime()));
         days[i] = df.format(calendarGlobal.getTime());




        e01.setText("11");
         e01.setTag(days[1]);
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: e01.setTag(days[1]); replace with e01.setTag(elevenString);

Comment: but i want to show on e01.text("11" only when click show full value 2013/09/11 on Toast

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some edit on the type

First, on onClick method, change value to String value and e01 to v

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.e01:
        String value = v.getTag().toString();       // change here
        Toast.makeText(this, value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show();
```

Second, change button e01 to following and instance it. In you code, you forgot to instance your button.

```
 Button e01 = (Button) findElementById(R.id.e01);
```

Comment: i did instance button buton work perfectly if i add  e01.setText(days[1]);
    e01.setTag(days[1]); both show same value on text and on click but i want to show on text only ("11")

Comment: e01.gettag() work finw only problem how i will show("11") on e01.text

Comment: e01.tag on lcickshow full date perfectly2013/09/11 only problem how i wil show only("11") on e01.settext????

Comment: e01.tag on lcickshow full date perfectly2013/09/11 only problem how i wil show only("11") on e01.settext????

Comment: Your code should work perfectly. Can you do some test by change setText to e01.setText("11"); , will it show you "11"?

Comment: if i witte  e01.setText("11"); manually is show perfectly 11 on text and on click show ful dates

Comment: yes it will show "11" when put manually problem is split string i guess

Comment: No,you split should be no problems, I guess is your days[1]. Can you check your days[1] value?

Comment: Strange... Then it should be works. Can you updated your code again. I really can't figure out anything wrong with your code.